# Drawing Round Rectangles on Theme.Wallpaper Background

Tags: android, background, drawing, shapes, wallpaper

I am new here, and I have a question. I hope someone can point me in the right direction. I'd appreciate it very much.

I have started making an app which sets the user's phone wallpaper as the background for the app (using --> android:theme="@style/Theme.Wallpaper").

I want to draw a few simple round rectangles on top of this background. Eventually, I want to be able to swipe the rectangles off the screen, and fill the rectangles with new content.

What might the code look like, and what is the best approach? I am guessing OpenGL is preferable over Canvas/Drawables?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: After spinning my wheels for a while, I've decided to go with OpenGL using a translucent background!